# VB.NET: Code runs without error, but does not add item to listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I've got this embedded CMD on my form which I created using another person's code and everything works right. Inside one of the Private Subs (that seems to run every time a new line is written in the CMD output textbox), I've got a line which adds a item to a listbox (listboxs name is txtPlayerList) on another form labelled Status.

When this area of the code runs, it doesn't throw up any errors (and if I put a msgbox() on the same line, the msgbox() works). If I put the add to listbox line on form_load it works perfectly?

Here is my code, I've included everything from that form just in case (it is in the third sub from the top with the asterisks and comment **"Get players and maybe other stuff as well"**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Console

Public WithEvents MyProcess As Process
Private Delegate Sub AppendOutputTextDelegate(ByVal text As String)
Public LastLine As String
Public LastLineFormatted As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim LocalpathParent As String = Application.StartupPath() + "\MCserver"

    'loads embed cmd
    Me.AcceptButton = ExecuteButton
    MyProcess = New Process
    With MyProcess.StartInfo
        .FileName = "CMD.EXE"
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .WorkingDirectory = LocalpathParent
    End With
    MyProcess.Start()

    MyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()
    MyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()
    AppendOutputText("Process Started at: " & MyProcess.StartTime.ToString)

    'Resize with parent mdi container. Needs to be anchored & StartPosition = manual in properties
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

End Sub

Private Sub MyProcess_ErrorDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.ErrorDataReceived
    AppendOutputText(vbCrLf & "Error: " & e.Data)
End Sub

Private Sub MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles MyProcess.OutputDataReceived
    AppendOutputText(vbCrLf & e.Data)

    '*****************************************
    'Get Players and maybe other stuff as well
    '*****************************************

    LastLine = Me.OutputTextBox.Lines.Last
    If Status.ServerStarted = True Then

        If Me.LastLine.Contains(" joined the game") Then
            LastLineFormatted = Me.LastLine
            LastLineFormatted = LastLineFormatted.Replace(" joined the game", "")

            '***THIS LINE BELOW WORKS IN FORM LOAD, BUT NOT HERE FOR SOME REASON???***

            Status.txtPlayersList.Items.Add(LastLineFormatted)
            MsgBox("add lastlineformatted")

        ElseIf Me.LastLine.Contains(" left the game") Then
            LastLineFormatted = Me.LastLine
            LastLineFormatted = LastLineFormatted.Replace(" left the game", "")

            Status.txtPlayersList.Items.Remove(LastLineFormatted)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ExecuteButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    MyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(InputTextBox.Text)
    MyProcess.StandardInput.Flush()
    InputTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub AppendOutputText(ByVal text As String)
    If OutputTextBox.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim myDelegate As New AppendOutputTextDelegate(AddressOf AppendOutputText)
        Try
            Me.Invoke(myDelegate, text)
        Catch
        End Try
    Else
        Try
            OutputTextBox.AppendText(text)
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT: Below is the code I have for form1 per request**

'code

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Localpath As String
    Public Downloadpath As String
    Public LocalpathParent As String

    'when this form is closing, send stop to console to make sure it has closed and saved
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Console.MyProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("stop") 'send an EXIT command to the Command Prompt
        Application.Exit()
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'load stuff in background n stuff
        Me.Show()
        Me.Focus()
        Configure.Show()
        Configure.Hide()
        Status.Show()
        Status.Hide()
        Console.Show()
        Console.Hide()
    End Sub

    'CONSOLE.form
    Private Sub ConsoleToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConsoleToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        'Hide all forms
        Status.Hide()
        Configure.Hide()
        'Shown Form that you want to load
        Console.Opacity = 100
        Console.Show()
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Console.MdiParent = Me

        Console.OutputTextBox.SelectionStart = Console.OutputTextBox.Text.Length
        Console.OutputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

    'STATUS.form
    Private Sub StatusToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StatusToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        'hide all forms
        Console.Hide()
        Configure.Hide()
        'Show Form that you want to load
        Status.Opacity = 100
        Status.Show()
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Configure.Size = Me.Size
        Status.MdiParent = Me
    End Sub

    'CONFIGURE.form
    Private Sub ConfigurationToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConfigurationToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        'hide all forms
        Status.Hide()
        Console.Hide()
        'Show form that you want to load
        Configure.Opacity = 100
        Configure.Show()
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Configure.Size = Me.Size
        Configure.MdiParent = Me
    End Sub
End Class
```

'code

Comment: You say you've included all your code, but **Status** isn't defined anywhere in it. What is Status please so that we can verify your code. Thanks Oh yes - I'm presuming that the Class Console is your main form?

Comment: I've got a main form named form1, which then has three other forms: console, status, and configure. I can post the status form but everything seems to be working on it.

Comment: How and where are you creating an instance of Status?

Comment: I didn't think I had to do that; but I've just written 'dim status1 as new status' and changed the lines reference to status1 instead... It still doesn't do anything different. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yep. Visual studio only creates the Class definition, not an instance of the form. You'll need to do the same for Your other forms - Console and Configure. and access them in the same way as my answer below. I think that should work for you - Hopefully..... Fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your original code to create an embeded CMD window was interfering with the code to update the listbox in another mdi child. After finding another way to embed a cmd console, and some fiddling around, It seems to be working Ok.   I haven't been able to test pure server output yet though.

THere have been quite a few changes to the code that are too big to post here, but the Alternative embedded CMD is this.

Place this in general form declarations

```
'command prompt variables
Private strResults As String
Private intStop As Integer
Private swWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
Friend thrdCMD As System.Threading.Thread
Private Delegate Sub cmdUpdate()
Private uFin As New cmdUpdate(AddressOf UpdateText)
Public WithEvents procCMDWin As New Process
```

This in your form_load Sub

```
    thrdCMD = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Prompt)
    thrdCMD.IsBackground = True
    thrdCMD.Start()
```

and these declarations within your form Class

```
Private Sub Prompt()
    AddHandler procCMDWin.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf CMDOutput
    AddHandler procCMDWin.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf CMDOutput
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    procCMDWin.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = LocalpathParent
    procCMDWin.Start()
    procCMDWin.BeginOutputReadLine()
    swWriter = procCMDWin.StandardInput
    Do Until (procCMDWin.HasExited)
    Loop
    procCMDWin.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateText()
    OutputTextBox.Text += strResults
    OutputTextBox.SelectionStart = OutputTextBox.TextLength - 1
    InputTextBox.Focus()
    intStop = OutputTextBox.SelectionStart
    OutputTextBox.ScrollToCaret()
    If OutputTextBox.Lines.Count > 2 Then
        LastLine = OutputTextBox.Lines.ElementAt(OutputTextBox.Lines.Count - 2)
        If Status.ServerStarted = True Then
            'get element 1 of split
            If LastLine.Contains(" joined the game") Then
                LastLineFormatted = ExtractName(LastLine, " joined the game")
                'If listlineformatted.contains(Players.allitems) then do
                Status.txtPlayersList.Items.Add(LastLineFormatted)
                Status.Show()
            ElseIf Me.LastLine.Contains(" left the game") Then
                LastLineFormatted = ExtractName(LastLine, " left the game")
                'If listlineformatted.contains(Players.allitems) then do
                Status.txtPlayersList.Items.Remove(LastLineFormatted)
                MsgBox("remove lastlineformatted")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ExtractName(unformattedString As String, stringToRemove As String) As String
    Dim temp As String = Split(unformattedString, "Server]")(1).ToString
    ExtractName = temp.Replace(stringToRemove, "")
End Function

Private Sub CMDOutput(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal OutputLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    strResults = OutputLine.Data & Environment.NewLine
    Invoke(uFin)
End Sub
```

Comment: I've created all the forms using the design view and using project-->add Windows form. All I really do in form1 is show and hide the forms using a menustrip

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the Form1 code please and I can make sure that the other forms are declared properly? No offense intended of course.

Comment: Time for bed here - It's 00:38

Comment: Easy done. Hopefully we can solve this problem tomorrow if you feel up for it. I've edited the original question to have the code from form1.

Comment: OK i'm trying to replicate your program as much as possible - but i'm getting a cross thread operation error on this line in your console form..    LastLine = OutputTextBox.Lines.Last. The error is an InvalidOperationException ...  Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'OutputTextBox' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. ... Have you been getting this at all?

Comment: No -- I haven't, but it looks like it might be part of my problem. I can try put my project onto GitHub if you'd like or? On the console's design form I have two textboxes. One of them is labelled outputtextbox (and is multi line) and the other inputtextbox

Comment: This is the code I used for the console form...  https://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/02/04/launching-and-controlling-external-applications-from-vb-net-application/

Comment: No problem I'm getting there - Though one of the problems I've found with gui programs is that although it's easy to copy and paste code, it's not so straightforward to give somebody the ui settings This is only a suggestion, but would it be easier to email me your solution? I promise I wont steal it ;-)

Comment: I just sent the google drive link to your email, with instructions. Steal all you like :)

Comment: Hehe. The line of code that youre having a problem with IS being added to a listbox, but it's being added to a different instance of the Status form. This other instance isnt an mdi child for some reason. I'm just trying to figure out how this other instance is being created at the moment. When I've got that, it should be "easy"

Comment: OK Getting there. It seems that where the CMD console is being created in a separate process, somehow the Status form is also being instantiated in this second process and THAT's the form that is getting the line added. Not your MDI child Status form. Hmmmmm. So somewhere along the line the code you got for the embedded cmd console is  messing things up.

Comment: I have to do a few things and i'll be back to have more  of a look

Comment: Hi Harry I think I have it working now - though I can't test whether you program will respond to purely server generated output - Is there I way I can do this